# Getting all controllers and their public ActionResults

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I have the below code currently working and it gives back a list of all public methods that return an ActionResult and the name of their respective controllers. That is:

> [{Controller = "ControllerName", Action = "ActionName"}, {...}, {...}
>   ...]

I am trying to figure out how I can tweak this to get the name of all action results and their respective controller objects, like this:

> [{Controller = {ControllerObject}, Action = "ActionName"}, {...}, {...}
>   ...]

Anyone have any idea how this might be accomplished?

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyDLL.MvcApplication));

var controllerActionList = asm.GetTypes()
    .Where(type => typeof(Controller).IsAssignableFrom(type))
    .SelectMany(type => type.GetMethods())
    .Where(
        m => m.IsPublic && m.ReturnType.Name == "ActionResult")
    .Select(x => new { Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name, Action = x.Name })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Isn't it just to remove `.Name`, i.e. change `{ Controller = x.DeclaringType.Name, Action = x.Name }`to `{ Controller = x.DeclaringType, Action = x.Name }`

Comment: So you want an instance of the controller? What for?

Comment: Thanks @mortb that is what I needed I think. As to your question Peter Bons, I am running a security test on all public actions to make sure they have a security attribute and that the security attribute is working as intended. I need the controller object to be able to make the checks.